# How to keep a javascript script running after user leaves page?

Tags: javascript, php, session

I'm currently creating a site that likes and follows users on Instagram. Once the user starts the script, it could go on for hours or days depending on the users input.

My issue is, when the user leaves the page, the script stops, is there any way the script could continue running, even if the user leaves the page or site? So that when the user returns, they can see the status of the script. Is there any way I could do this with just javascript? And could the script still run when the user exits their browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser is what runs JavaScript, so this is impossible. There are server-side JS solutions like node.js though, maybe look into those if you really want to use JavaScript.

Another perhaps easier option is to make an asynchronous request with JavaScript, passing data from the UI, then do the work on the server with a scripting language like PHP or Python.